# Ejecutar un Asynctask dentro de un fragment con un listview

Tags: android, android-fragment, listview, android-asynctask

Tengo un `Asynctask` que obtiene datos de un webservice y estos datos el usuario los ve mediante un lisview, pero ahora deseo introducir el `listview` en un `fragment`. pero no lo logro. Bueno el fragment aparece donde estoy usando un `VIewPAger` que lo genera automáticamente Android Studio.

**Fragment**

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_swipe_carros, container, false);
            //TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            //textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            new AsyncRetrieve().execute();
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Carro 1";
                case 1:
                    return "Carro 2";
                case 2:
                    return "Carro 3";
                case 3:
                    return "Carro 4";
                case 4:
                    return "Carro 5";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    private class AsyncRetrieve extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(swipe_carros.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pdLoading.setMessage("\tCargando cuentas...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/ver_cuentas_expositor/vercuentasexpo.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {


                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();


                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }


                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(swipe_carros.this);
                alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
                alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar las cuentas. Intentelo de nuevo.");
                alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                alertaDeError.create();
                alertaDeError.show();
            } else {
                //Existen Datos
                List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();
                //Parsea la respuesta obtenida por el Asynctask
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                try {
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
                        try {
                            preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            assert preguntaDatos != null;
                            pregrespcomment =" Cuenta expositor " + "\n" +"- Correo electronico: "+ preguntaDatos.getString("email_expositor") + "\n"+"- Contraseña: " + preguntaDatos.getString("password_expositor");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        preguntas.add(pregrespcomment);

                    }

                    //crear el Adapter.
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(swipe_carros.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
                    //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
                    mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);
                    mostrarr.getAdapter().getCount();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total de cuentas expositor creadas: " + mostrarr.getAdapter().getCount() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(swipe_carros.this);
                    alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
                    alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no existen cuentas para mostrar. Intentelo de nuevo.");
                    alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
                    alertaDeError.create();
                    alertaDeError.show();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el **Asynctask** esta fuera del `fragment` pero en la misma clase y el XML asociado solo contiene el `listview. La pregunta es donde uso el asynctask y como lo ejecuto dentro del fragment.

Comment: Donde esta el asynkTask

Comment: Ahora, en ninguna parte, lo intente colocar dentro del oncreateview, pero me los marca en rojo y lo otro que intente fue colocarlo fuera del fragment pero dentro de la clase y llamarlo pero tampoco me resulto, Donde debería ir ? @David

Comment: La clase del AsyncTask donde la declaraste?

Comment: En la clase del viewpager, fuera del fragment @David

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el AsyncTask donde lo tenias

Comment: @David ya la he editado, lo tenia en el OnCreateView

Answer (score 0):

He reorganizado tu código y al `AsyncTask` le quite el `static`, recuerda que cuando declaras algo como static, pertenece a la clase y no al objeto.

AsyncTask es su genérico recibe tres tipos de datos, esto es genérico `AsyncTask<String, String, String>`. El primer tipo de dato define el parámetro que recibe AsyncTask al ser llamado, si se define como tipo Void `AsyncTask<Void, String, String>` AsyncTask no recibe ningún tipo de parámetro.

Cuando llamas a AsyncTask le tienes que pasar un parámetro porque así lo tienes definido, si no quieres pasarle un parámetro al llamarlo, define el primer tipo de dato en el genérico como `Void`.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {}


    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_detalle_carros, container, false);
        // TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        //textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        ListView mostrar=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista);

        // Los llamas así. Al llamarlo antes te daba error porque lo estabas declarando
        // static. y lo estatic solo puede ser llamado directamente desde la clase, no 
        // desde un objeto y una instancia es un objeto.
        new AsyncRetrieve.execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "CARRO 1";
                case 1:
                    return "CARRO 2";
                case 2:
                    return "CARRO 3";
                case 3:
                    return "CARRO 4";
                case 4:
                    return "CARRO 5";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Al definir el primer tipo de dato como Void, AsyncTask no recibe
     * parametros al ser llamado con el metodo execute().
     */
    private class AsyncRetrieve extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(lista_detalle_carros.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pdLoading.setMessage("\tCargando cuentas...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/ver_cuentas_expositor/vercuentasexpo.php");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }

            try {


                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();


                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }


                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(lista_detalle_carros.this);
                alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
                alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar las cuentas. Intentelo de nuevo.");
                alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                alertaDeError.create();
                alertaDeError.show();
            } else {
                //Existen Datos
                List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();
                //Parsea la respuesta obtenida por el Asynctask
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                try {
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
                        try {
                            preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            assert preguntaDatos != null;
                            pregrespcomment =" Cuenta expositor " + "\n" +"- Correo electronico: "+ preguntaDatos.getString("email_expositor") + "\n"+"- Contraseña: " + preguntaDatos.getString("password_expositor");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        preguntas.add(pregrespcomment);

                    }

                    //crear el Adapter.
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(lista_detalle_carros.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
                    //Asignar el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
                    mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);
                    mostrarr.getAdapter().getCount();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total de cuentas expositor creadas: " + mostrarr.getAdapter().getCount() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(lista_detalle_carros.this);
                    alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
                    alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no existen cuentas para mostrar. Intentelo de nuevo.");
                    alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
                    alertaDeError.create();
                    alertaDeError.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Copia y pega este código asi mismo como esta y me dejas saber si te da error.

Comment: No, genera error, pero para llamarlo en el fragment ?

Comment: He editado mi pregunta, en el método `onCreateView()` muestro como llamarlo.

Comment: Si, pero cuando lo llame de una actividad no me pide parámetros y ahora sí ... Ya que es asyn es un consulta a la bd

Comment: He editado mi respuesta por segunda vez. Si quieres entender mejor como funciona `AsyncTask` visita este [repositorio](https://gitlab.com/david-minaya/AsyncTask), en el explico mas detalladamente su funcionamiento.

Comment: marca en rojo el execute();

Comment: @Ash Después de modificar que te marcar el `execute()` en rojo? Recuerda que el `AsyncTask` no debe ser `static`. Sube una captura de pantalla del error y comparte el enlace.

Comment: he agregado una captura

Comment: Cuando pones el puntero sobre el `AsyncRetriever`, donde te marca el error, que es exactamente lo que te dice?

Comment: Marcar como static o no static y he marcado no static y despues el fragment me marca error :/

Comment: Que tipo de error?

Comment: Me dice que no puede resolver el metodo desde un contexto estatico y me da la opcion de Marcar el asynck como estatico y no estatico,

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66840/discussion-between-david-and-ash).